# CUDA: What is the thread block limitation of devices whose compute capability is 1.0?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, tesla

Recently, I am reading the book 'Programming Massively Parallel processors'. One of the reading exercise in chapter 3 ask me to detect which assignment for SM is possible. The problem looks like below

**Indicate which of the following assignments per multiprocessor is possible:**

1. 8 blocks with 128 threads each on a device with compute capability 1.0.
2. 8 blocks with 128 threads each on a device with compute capability 1.2.
3. 8 blocks with 128 threads each on a device with compute capability 3.0.
4. 16 blocks with 64 threads each on a device with compute capability 1.0.
5. 16 blocks with 64 threads each on a device with compute capability 1.2.
6. 16 blocks with 64 threads each on a device with compute capability 3.0.

From the most recent CUDA programming guild, I only find the specification for compute capability 3.0 whose allows up to 16 blocks and 2048 threads per SM and up 1024 threads per block. Unfortunately, I did not find any information related to compute capability 1.0.

Can anyone tell me where to find the block specification for compute capability 1.0? Thank you very much

Comment: NVIDIA maintains an [archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) of old CUDA versions going back some ten years. You could also perform a quick Google search for older versions of the CUDA Programming Guide, such as [this copy](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~ramani/cmsc828e_gpusci/CUDA21.pdf) of the guide for CUDA 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the page of [CUDA in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA), there is a valid specification to all devices. it will be in **Compute capability (version) section**.

But here is a photo about it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Koviroli! Thank helps.